# R- Make graphics depending the hour

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm newbie with R, and I would like to make some graphics depending the hour,
I have this in my dataset:

> date: 29/11/2011 7:30----29/11/2011 8:30----29/11/2011 9:30
>
> value: 53,77----72,74----44,28

Do I need to split it first? or I can make graphics whith just that format

cheers

Comment: what is the desired output and what graphics do you want to make?

Comment: What does `53,77` mean? Is it "," indicative of two separate values or is it a decimal place?

Comment: it's a decimal. I would like to make a bar graphic for example

Comment: `date.parsed = lubridate::ymd_hms(date)` then `hour = lubridate::hour(date.parsed)` then something like `ggplot(data,aes(x=hour,y=value)) + geom_col()`